# Working with Bootstrap 3 classes but for only half of the page

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, dom, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need two divs to sit side by side, and inside those divs will be divs that have bootstrap 3 classes. The problem is that when I restrict the left div, for example, to 50% by using `col-xs-6`, the `col-xs-...` classes on the child elements then only respond to their parent's width.

For clarity:
[image]

The purple divs' widths are based on a percentage of their parent, whereas I'd like them to be the same width as though they were a direct child of `container` whilst being able to keep them separate (and wrap them) from the other adjacent div (each div labelled `col-xs-6` will be rendered from entirely different server-side controls).

**NOTE:** Ignore the fact I'm styling these for an XS display for now, this is only temporary while I work out the styles then I'll amend them accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the three purple divs you would use col-xs-4

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

The sum of the inner divs should add up to 12

Answer (score 0):

You should add another row internally to create a new instance of your 12 columns. You might want to have a look at what Bootstrap calls [Nesting Columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 blue-back">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 black-back">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 black-back odd">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 black-back">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 blue-back">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 black-back">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 black-back odd">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-4 black-back">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8fwNZ/)